# Invoking ActivateBuildFailureTarget only on a build failure

Tags: f#, f#-fake

Working with FAKE 4 (Legacy), I am not able to identify documentation on the properly use of ActivateBuildFailureTarget. My end goal is that the BuildFailureTarget that I've defined only gets called when the build fails within a specific Target. As alluded to, I have already created a BuildFailureTarget.